# Ubuntu 12.10 no window focus on help browser

Tags: linux, interface, ubuntu

The help browser is not getting window focus when clicked on it. Clicking links or buttons in the help browser works without window focus, but copying code or typing in it doesn't.
I can get window focus on the help browser by using the alt+tab or the Window menu.

I'm running Mathematica 8.0.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.10.
Mathematica is the only software that has this behavior, that's why i post this question here.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior or know a solution to it?

edit: switching focus between notebooks behaves normally.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this problem.  So it's not just you.  Unfortunately I don't have a solution (didn't use it much on Linux).

Comment: You might want to try your luck at [ubuntu.se]

Comment: I have posted the question at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216589/wolfram-mathematica-on-ubuntu-12-10-no-window-focus-on-help-browser).

Comment: Tried this? http://www.hrstc.org/node/21 don't know if it still works since that is tagged hardy

Comment: The option "Enable support to enter complex characters" is not present in Ubuntu 12.10 anymore. At least, i could not find it anymore in the Language Support in System Settings.
However, it seems this might be the problem. I'll keep looking for a way to fix it.

Comment: I've seen this issue a couple of times and haven't yet seen a solution. It appears that the Mathematica notebook doesn't give up its focus. I use Alt-Tab to get around this (Hit Alt-Tab to select the window in Focus). I wonder whether swapping out Mathematica's QT libraries might fix the issue...

Comment: On my box this is only appears when I use the Unity desktop. If I choose Gnome on startup, the Doc-Center gets focus when I click on it.

Comment: I don't have Gnome installed so i can't check whether the problem could be due to Unity but i can't remember having this problem in Ubuntu 10.04 (last release i used, 2 years ago).